# How to join distant stations in OpenTTD on Android?

Tags: openttd

On desktop, if the feature is enabled and you place a station with Ctrl, the game will ask you if you want to connect it to an existing station nearby.

How to do this on Android version of the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally remembered. There is actually a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button at the edge of the screen. Anything that uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in desktop version uses this button instead.

[image]